# Apache mod rewrite conditional

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a .htaccess file with the following contents

```
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\/image\/)
#RewriteRule . image.php

RewriteRule . index.php
```

What is the correct way to instruct apache to send requests to image.php if /image/ is found in the request url, if not, i want index.php to handle the requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle the requests without providing a redirect you can do something like this provided you have your `image.php` file configured to handle the request. We're telling Apache if you find a string beginning with "image" to load the `image.php` file and [stop processing the rest of the htaccess file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html).

```
RewriteEngine on
#If we find image, then load image.php
RewriteRule ^/?image image.php [L]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php
```